# Manage NTFS Share Permissions via GPO

Tags: permissions, group-policy, ntfs

I've seen you can manage NTFS permissions on a share using a Windows GPO. Searching around I've come across [this](https://www.lepide.com/how-to/assign-permissions-to-files-folders-through-group-policy.html) article and have followed it but had no joy getting it to work.
I've run `gpupdate /force` on the target Windows Server but the permissions on the folders have not updated.

Is anyone managing share permissions via GPO successfully?

Comment: Can you check the `System` event log just after `gpupdate /force`, and `Applications and Service Logs` -> Microsoft -> Windows -> Group policy -> Operational ?

Additionally, can you run `gpresult /h c:\temp\report.html` to save an HTML report and see if you can find useful informations ?